# MySQL SELECT WHERE ..... IF

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement

I have done a small chat with PHP and MySQL. But now I'm through an issue: I want to make a query such that if the messages are set as private, I load them only if they were sent to this user. If they aren't private, just load them all.

I know I need a "if" somewhat. But how could I do that? My code looks like:

```
SELECT message, private, FromPerson, ToPerson 
FROM chat WHERE time > '$time' 
and FromPerson != '$user_id' 
AND IF (private = '1') ToPerson = '$user_id'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A `WHERE` clause is already an 'IF'.

Comment: @MarcB In the context of the question, that's right. In general, that's not right. This is a dangerous comment to make to a beginner...

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of achieving this, amongst which:

```
AND (private <> '1' OR ToPerson = '$user_id')
```

Which pretty much means "either it's not a private message, or it's addressed to that specific user"; or

```
AND IF(private = '1', ToPerson = '$user_id', TRUE)
```

Which is pretty self-explanatory.

Last comment: for the love of God, please use prepared statements and don't inline external input into your SQL, or SQL injection will kick your butt sooner or later.

Comment: Good! Thank you, Romain. This was my first question here on StackOverflow.